# How to mock string class in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a Test method which is like this

```
[Test]
public void VerifyRedirectedTempCodeWithAnEmptyString()
{
    var mockStringLength = new Mock<string>();
    mockStringLength.Setup(x => x.Length).Returns(0);
    Boolean returnValue = VerifyRedirectedTempCode(mockStringLength.Object);
    Assert.AreEqual(returnValue, false);
}
```

There is no compilation error, but when I run this test its giving 
System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class. here is my actual method

```
    public virtual Boolean VerifyRedirectedTempCode(string tempAuthCode)
    {
        if (tempAuthCode != null && tempAuthCode.Length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So, how to mock the string.length property.So that even in future if they update the length method it should not affect my test method. How to mock?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? I don't think that they will change the functionality of the `Length` property anytime. What does you `VerifyRedirectedTempCode()` method do?

Comment: It has the same functionality as string.IsNullOrEmpty, just that I am using this method I wanted to mock .length I have kept the method in the question(edited)

Comment: The `NotSupportedException` message is quite clear here. Moq works by creating a new class dynamically which derives from or implements the type you want to mock. If the latter type is `sealed` Moq cannot inherit from it, and [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is a `sealed class` for sure. You should not use mocks but real strings to test your method.

Comment: Note that your actual method could be simplified to just `public virtual bool VerifyRedirectedTempCode(string tempAuthCode) { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempAuthCode); }`.

Comment: thanks, As I am new to Moq did not know what to mock.this helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mock the string length here. The method you're testing expects an integer, so just pass it an integer! If you really want you can pass it `string.Empty.Length`, in case this changes in a future version of the framework.

With a unit test, you're testing the behaviour of a method given its inputs and the state of its dependencies. If your method takes an `int` and returns a `bool` then all you need to do to test it is to pass in an `int`. The method shouldn't care where it came from. This is a matter of separation of concerns.

---

Following your update, given your method takes a `string` you just need to test its behaviour given different string inputs. At least `null`, `string.Empty`, and some valid `string`.

You can't expect your test to never fail as you change your method's  implementation. In fact, you should change your test first so it DOES fail, the change your code so the tests pass, then refactor. This is called the red, green, refactor cycle.

---

It seems like your validator is probably part of a larger piece of work and maybe what you're really interested in testing is how the rest of your code behaves given the different potential validation results. In this case, I would recommend that you extract your validation logic into a separate class whose interface you can then mock. Supply the validator as a dependency to the code that needs it. Then, in your tests you can supply a mock validator that behaves in a predetermined way. That way you can write your tests without worrying that a future change to the validator logic will break them. This seems to be the essence of your question.

Comment: sorry I should have posted my method in first place, I have edited my question ,can you check now

Comment: @user3324848 I have updated my answer again, addressing the issue of writing tests that are not brittle in the case of changes to the validation logic. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: I think it answered a part of my question , I understood that we need to mock a validation method if its big and can change in future, but In this case I was not trying that ,I was just trying to mock string.length property so that my test case doesnt depend on that property

Comment: It's not possible to mock that property using normal mocking frameworks, TypeMock or Microsoft Fakes might let you override that behaviour but honestly, if you feel like you need to mock that I think you probably need to rethink your tests. Please accept my answer if I've helped you solve your problem :)